# Plugin MySQL SELECT custom data and filter on user meta

Tags: plugin-development, mysql, user-meta

I'm porting a custom PHP feature to be part of a Wordpress plugin.

At present, my USERS table has a field (let's call it FLAG) which my MySQL query needs to filter on, eg:

```
SELECT custom-data
  FROM custom-table JOIN users ON some-match
 WHERE some-condition AND users.flag='1'
 GROUP BY username
```

Obviously, within my WordPress plugin, I have implemented `flag` as user-meta.

But how can I use this in a MySQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a proper SQL query in the question is not possible to write a proper query in the response, but following your pseudo-code approach:

```
SELECT custom-data
  FROM custom-table
  LEFT JOIN wp_users ON custom_data.user_id = wp_users.ID
  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
 WHERE some-condition
   AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'flag'
   AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = 'flagvalue'
```

So basically, you need to join against wp_usermeta, which is where you'd be storing your users "flag".